# BrowserWindowOpener how to set address

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I am using vaadin 8 and have a html file, which I am showing it as :

```
    StreamResource streamResource = createHTMLStreamResource();
    BrowserWindowOpener opener = new BrowserWindowOpener(streamResource);
    opener.setWindowName("PRISMA");
    opener.setFeatures("location=0");
    opener.extend(generateReportButton);
```

It opens a new window and shows the html content. that works great. But the address of it is http://localhost:8080/APP/connector/0/2373/url/PRISMAReport.html. Not sure from where "APP/connector/0/2373/url/" is coming from. But how I can remove it or set it up?

Answer (score 1):

The URL is managed by the resource implementation. In the case of a `StreamResource`, the URL will be a an internal URL that is handled by the Vaadin framework to serve bytes that are configured in `createHTMLStreamResource()`.

If you want more control over the URL, then you need to also take control over how requests to that URL are handled e.g. by registering your own servlet to handle the requests. You can use the `BrowserWindowOpener` constructor that takes a `String` parameter if you want to define your own custom URL.

Comment: can you provide me 1 example please

Comment: Step one is to change the existing code to use `new BrowserWindowOpener("some/url");`. Step two is to implement a servlet mapped to that URL that does whatever you want to do. You can refer to any existing guide about creating servlets for that.